# Как с помощью рекурсии преобразовать строку по точке в вложенные обьекты

Tags: javascript

Моя функция принимает следующего вида строку

```
'a.b.c.d.e'
```

на выходе я должен получить такой обьект

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":{}}}}}}
```

с помощью reduce данную задачу можно решить вот так

```
function namespace(s) {
     return s.split('.').reverse().reduce((acc, a)=>{
        let n = {};
        return n[a] = acc, n
      },{})
}
```

но как сделать это с помощью рекурсивного обхода?

Comment: переоткрыл. Старайся более подробные описания давать

Comment: спасибо, хорошо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 3):

Для написания рекурсивной функции нужно определиться как минимум с двумя вещами:

1. условия выхода из рекурсии
2. какие действия должны повторяться

---

### Условия выхода из рекурсии

Первое что нужно сделать - определиться, когда нужно закончить рекурсию.

В данном случае очевидно, что если передали пустой путь - то не для чего запускать рекурсию. В этом случае надо просто вернуть либо пустой объект, который потом будет заворачиваться в объекты по мере выхода из рекурсии, либо накопленный результат.

### Какие действия должны повторяться

Можно выделить повторяющиеся действия, а именно:

1. получение ключа и создание объекта
2. определение, что нужно передать на следующий шаг рекурсии

Например:

из задачи видно, что нужно создать объект, у которого ключ соответствует элементу массива

- `{ a: {...}}`
- `{ b: {...}}`
- `{ c: {...}}`
  и так далее.

То есть, можно заметить, что если убрать первый элемент массива, то останется та же самая структура

- `{ b: {...}}`
- `{ c: {...}}`

таким образом, вместо `{...}` можно записать рекурсивный вызов функции, передав ей тот же самый массив, без первого элемента.

например, можно воспользоваться [деструктуризацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) и сразу получить отдельно первый элемент и все элементы массива без первого

```
var [head, ...tail] = path;
```

далее достаточно создать объект

```
var obj = { [head]: fun(tail) }
```

и вернуть этот объект из функции.

---

Примеры реализации:

```js
function fun(path) {
  if (path.length == 0) return {}; // возвращаем пустой объект и выходим из рекурсии

  var [key, ...rest] = path; // определяем текущий ключ
  return { // возвращаем объект с нужным ключом и уходим в рекурсию.
    [key]: fun(rest)
  };
}

console.log(fun('a.b.c.d.e'.split('.')));
```

```js
function fun(path, acc = {}) { // накапливаем результат в параметре `acc`
  if (path.length == 0) return acc; // если пришел пустой путь - возвращаем накопленное значение

  var key = path.pop(); // определяем текущий ключ

  // рекурсивно вызываем функцию, передавая вторым параметром накопленный результат
  return fun(path, {
    [key]: acc
  });
}

console.log(fun('a.b.c.d.e'.split('.')));
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что [.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) меняет массив, к которому применяется, удаляя из него **последний** элемент. Поэтому дополнительных преобразований `path` перед передачей в рекурсивный вызов - не нужно.

Для того чтобы функция принимала строку, достаточно написать обертку:

```
function namespace(s) {
  return fun(s.split('.'));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, было очень позновательно

Answer (score 1):

Если решать без функций-обёрток, только с одной рекурсивной функцией, принимающей строку, но можно, например, такими двумя способами:

```js
const path = 'a.b.c.d.e';

function namespace1(path, current = {}, main = current) {
  const fields = path.split('.');
  const field = fields.shift();
  current[field] = {};

  if (fields.length === 0) return main;
  return namespace1(fields.join('.'), current[field], main);
}

function namespace2(path, current = {}) {
  const parent = {};

  const fields = path.split('.');
  const field = fields.pop();
  parent[field] = current;

  if (fields.length === 0) return parent;
  return namespace2(fields.join('.'), parent);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(namespace1(path)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(namespace2(path)));
```

Comment: без оберток, лучше и без split тогда решать: откусывать по точкам из строки

Comment: Да, можно и строками обойтись.